# Dictionary within a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Suppose I have a csv file called website.csv:

```
facebook.com        a social network website
twitter.com         another social network website
facebook.com        a social website
facebook.com        a website
twitter.com         another network website 
youtube.com         a website like facebook but to share videos
youtube.com         a video sharing website
```

And I want to create a dictionary that contains the name of the website (as key) and the value is a dictionary of words in the description, that takes each word as key, and the frequency of the occurrence of words as value, and should include the variable '*TOTAL*' as the sum of the number of words in the description of each website.

This is the code that I created:

```
def webdescription(data):
    import csv
    data = website.csv
    csvreader = csv.reader(data)
    d = defaultdict(int)
    dfinal = {}
    for line in data:
        description_list = line[1].split()
        dfinal[line[0]] = d
        for each in description_list:
            d[each] += 1
            d['_TOTAL_'] = sum(d.itervalues())
    return dfinal
```

And the expected output should be:

```
{'facebook.com': {'a':3, 'social': 2, 'network':1, 'website':3, '_TOTAL_': 9}
{'twitter.com': {'another':2, 'social':1, 'network':2, 'website':2, '_TOTAL_': 7}
{'youtube.com': {'a':2, 'website':2, 'like': 1, 'sharing':1, 'share':1, 'video':1,     
'videos': 1, 'facebook': 1, '_TOTAL_':10}
```

And I didn't seem to get the expected output.
Help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: What is your output? how does it look?

Comment: my output does not incorporate all the descriptions for the same website, instead it prints {'facebook.com': {'a': 1, 'social': 1, 'network': 1, 'website': 1, '_TOTAL_': 4} and so on :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`website.csv`

```
facebook.com,a social network website
twitter.com,another social network website
facebook.com,a social website
facebook.com,a website
twitter.com,another network website 
youtube.com,a website like facebook but to share videos
youtube.com,a video sharing website
```

---

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> d = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> with open('website.csv') as f:
        for name, desc in csv.reader(f):
            words = desc.split()
            d[name].update(words)
            d[name]['TOTAL'] += len(words)


>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'facebook.com': Counter({'TOTAL': 9, 'a': 3, 'website': 3, 'social': 2, 'network': 1}), 'twitter.com': Counter({'TOTAL': 7, 'website': 2, 'network': 2, 'another': 2, 'social': 1}), 'youtube.com': Counter({'TOTAL': 12, 'a': 2, 'website': 2, 'sharing': 1, 'like': 1, 'videos': 1, 'share': 1, 'but': 1, 'to': 1, 'facebook': 1, 'video': 1})})
```

Comment: One thing though, what if the csv file actually contains more than 2 columns, and the website and the description are in the first and last columns respectively?

Comment: @FrederickAdler Small change, `for row in csv.reader(f)` `name, desc = row[0], row[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Your are always using the same d. You should create a new object for each new line, like

```
for line in data:
    description_list = line[1].split()
    d = dfinal[line[0]] = defaultdict(int)
```